# How to get the output of a function within a class from another class in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-class

Class that has the output is in another file

```py
class FileOp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.on1 = False
 
    def filenameis(self,parti):
        return parti
    def clickfun(self):
        if not self.on1:
            self.button_1.config(image = self.on)
            self.on1 = True
            #self.parti = 
            self.filenameis((r'\310'))
```

Class that needs the output of filenameis
how would I construct the this class to just print the return of "filenameis" without changing the output?

```py
self.fn = ''
self.fnb = Button(self,text="get name", command= lambda: self.fn = FileOp.filenameis )
print("this is what it prints",self.fn)


filename =  (r"C:\Users\15027\Desktop\real\Dataset"+filenameis+"\summary.csv")
```

Comment: your question is not clear enough. What is the problem? you cannot import class or?

Comment: I can import class, but return of filenameis print "<function FileOp.filenameis at 0x000001C655A3ED40>"

Comment: i want another file to read the output without changing the parameter value. it can run a function that has no item in parameter area.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre].  BTW, you cannot have assignment statement inside a lambda: `lambda: self.fn = FileOp.filenameis` will raise exception.